# How to keep footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have readed alot and still didn't position my footer proper. I am trying to position my footer to stay at the bottom of the page and be visible only when I scroll to the bottom.

I have added the folowing classes to the page:

```
<div class="wrap">

<!-- Holds all the page content inside -->

<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
.....
</div>
```

I have added the folowing css to the classes:

```
.wrap {
 min-height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding:5%;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
.footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 1;
}

.spacer, #footer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and preventing the footer to stay always at the bottom?

Comment: I thought it does that by default... mmhhh *confused*

Comment: So, what does it do instead now?

Comment: Can you create demo on jsfiddle.net with all your HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the footer class

```
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
```

This will keep the footer to the bottom

```
<div class="footer">
Your content
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this works, can you confirm? http://jsbin.com/yujotesaqa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I am suprised it's the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Position your footer as `absolute` and add `bottom: 0` to your footer class.

```
.footer {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't have `position: absolute`??

Comment: @Milkmannetje `right` is not needed, but I've added `left: 0`

Comment: @putvande Right, it should be `absolute`, since the complete code is not shown, I'm still in doubt if this will work

Answer (score 2):

More elegant solution would be like this

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;padding:0;
}
.fake-body{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.wrap {
 position:relative;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  color:white;
}

.spacer, #footer {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-body">
<div class="wrap">

<div class="spacer">spacer</div>

<div class="footer">footer</div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this screw up the whole layout?

Comment: @PraveenKumar look at css, that might happen, but styling is too small, you can easily modify it

Comment: Check the full screen version.

Comment: It's because `spacer height=300px;` but `fake-body height=200px;` for demo purpose,  so that scrollbar appears